# Can't read numbers from a text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to read a list of 12 grades from a text file. Each grade is on a new line in the text file. I have to find the lowest grade and drop it(in the text file as well), then find the average score of the grades. I am having trouble making the text values into integer values so I can find the average. I also can't figure out how to find the lowest grade and drop it.
Here is my code:

```
try:
    homeworkFile = open('homework.txt', 'r')
except:
    print("Error: invalid file")
else:
    lines = homeworkFile.readlines()
homeworkFile.close()

homeworkFile = open('homework.txt', 'w')

for line in lines:
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: by the way the values in the text document are:84.5
62
23
89.9
92
82
78
76.5
99
83
88
78.2

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is just one way to take all of your values and calculate the average.

```
input_file = input("enter file name: ") 
open_file = open(input_file, 'r')
```

Here I just put all of your values into notepad and read through it

```
grades_list = []
for grade in open_file:
    grade_format = grade.strip()    #how to remove extra blank space
    grades_list.append(grade_format)
```

Then I used a for-loop to go through each line and put the grades into a list

```
grade_convert = []    #new list for all of the converted values
for grade in grades_list:
    convert = float(grade)     #convert each value in the list into a float
    grade_convert.append(convert)
```

I used another list for converted each value

```
grade_convert = sorted(grade_convert)    #very first element will be the lowest
grade_convert.pop(0)    #permanently removes the very first item

grade_total = 0    #set a counter
for grade in grade_convert:    
    grade_total += grade    #add all of the values to the counter

grade_average = grade_total / len(grade_convert)    #len is number of items 
print(grade_average)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grades_list = []
for line in lines :`
    grade = float(line)
    grades_list.append(grade)
grades_list.sort()
lowest_grade = grades_list[0] #There is the lowest grade
```

Comment: when I added this it gives me the error "Index error: list index out of range"

Comment: Hello, it would be helpful if you added an explanation of your code to your answer. Code only answers are not as clear as they appear to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can structure your logic. You need to convert values to `float` pre-processing. Using `with` is recommended instead of using `open` and `close` explicitly.

```
import os

file = 'homework.txt'

# check if file exists
assert os.path.exists(file), "File does not exist: {0}".format(file)

# use with to open/close file implicitly
with open(mystr, 'w') as file_in:
    lines = homeworkFile.readlines()
    grades = sorted(float(line) for line in lines)

# drop lowest trade
del grades[0]
```